# MySQL Error: Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm working from the W3Schools tutorial for MySQL and it seems either some of the code is outdated or I'm just missing something utterly stupid. In trying to pass on information to a database, I get this error:

> Error: Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'

I'm attempting to pass info on from a form submission that then links to this page, where it grabs the info the user enters to create a new entry into the database.

Here is the code for the form submission.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="3ainsert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the other page:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $age)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're missing some of these " ' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isn't encasing the values in quotes:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";
```

However please note that generally using prepared statements is preferred over directly inserting into a query.

Comment: Wow. Okay. I feel like a dumb ass. Someone should update [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) so others don't fall into the same trap. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when the site allows me to.

Comment: @user3476944 Ohhh don't get us started on w3schools tsk tsk tsk

Comment: Why? Is it a generally bad website for this sort of thing? Is there a better place I could be learning from?

Comment: @Dagoth YES it has a bad reputation for poor info scattered within.  https://web.archive.org/web/20110412103745/http://w3fools.com If you are going to use php, use http://php.net/ .   Go to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ for mysql stuff.  When the manual doesn't help, come directly to StackOverflow and search like mad -- the answer is probably already here, it's just a matter of searching properly.